# Need Protractor and Chai help to get disable button expectation

Tags: protractor, chai

In my angular project we are using Protractor and Chai promise for e2e testing. I want to get assertion so I can test condition where I am testing button is on its disabled mode when it present on page. I have tried few of conditions but they passed both conditions (true/false).

```
expect(element(by.css('.save_edit_username')).getAttribute('disabled')).to.eventually.equal(true);
expect(element(by.css('.save_edit_username')).getText()).to.eventually.equal('Opslaannnnnnn');
expect(element(by.css('.save_edit_username')).isEnabled()).to.eventually.be.false;
expect(element(by.css('.save_edit_username')).isEnabled()).to.eventually.be.true;

this.Then(/^Save Button should be disabled$/, function (callback) {
   // above expect will go here......
});
```

Furthermore, I have tried basic true and false chai assertion but that also not worked.

```
expect(true).to.be.true;
expect(1).to.not.be.true;
```

```
expect(false).to.be.false;
expect(0).to.not.be.false;
```

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Damn! I got the same problem. Anyone know?

Comment: Just incase anyone is wondering, I solved my issue with ".to.eventually.be.false". I had a function that returned the promise<boolean> on the submitButton.isEnabled(). Not sure if that helps now lol

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me                   $.expect(page.buttonDisabled.isEnabled()).to.eventually.to.equal(false).and.notify(callback);;